# Как переопределить метод QAbstractItemModel::index?

Tags: c++, qt

Таким образом (см. фрагмент ниже) определить я не могу, поскольку в контексте дочернего класса относительно QAbstractItemModel этот конструктор приватный.

```
QModelIndex GridBasedModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return QModelIndex(row, column, static_cast<void*>(0), this);
}
```

Отсюда вопрос, как можно переопределить метод index?

Comment: Нужно использовать `protected`-метод `createIndex`